# Want to set the ArrayList name in string or TextView in retrofitV2

Tags: android, json, arraylist, retrofit2

I have the json respone

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "suggestion": {
        "message": {
            "message_a":"a",
            "message_b":"b"
        },
        "message1": {
            "message_a":"a",
            "message_b":"b"
        },
        "message2": {
            "message_a":"a",
            "message_b":"b"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set "message" and "message2" from response into String or TextView in retrofitV2

ApiInterface Class

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET(“url”)
Call<Contributor>getCheck();
}
```

Contributor

```
public class Contributor {
    @SerializedName("status")
    String status;
    @SerializedName("suggestion")
    ArrayList<Suggestion_List>suggestion;

    public String getName() {
            return name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Suggestion_List> getSuggestion() {
        return suggestion;
    }

}
```

This is the code still far i have done

Comment: provide your code

Comment: I have tried many times, But i'am not getting the logic what should i use - Yuri Popiv

Comment: At least I need URL and params to provide you some example code

Comment: Can you help me with the code, How should I make ArrayList and how to set the ArrayList key name in TextView using retrofit, And the GET response in the question is same response just the value is different  - Yuri Popiv

Comment: sure, but provide code with your API request, activity code etc..

Comment: I have edit my question -Yuri Popiv

Answer (score 0):

So if you cannot change response to `"message": {},"message": {},"message": {}` then parsing as JSONObject is the only way.

First create:

```
    public class Message {

        @SerializedName("message_a")
        private String message_a;
        @SerializedName("message_b")
        private String message_b;

    public Message(String message_a, String message_b) {
        this.message_a = message_a;
        this.message_b = message_b;
    }

        public String getMessage_a() {
            return message_a;
        }

        public void setMessage_a(String message_a) {
            this.message_a = message_a;
        }

        public String getMessage_b() {
            return message_b;
        }

        public void setMessage_b(String message_b) {
            this.message_b = message_b;
        }
    }
```

}

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("url")
    Call<JSONObject> getCheck();
}
```

And finnaly in your activity

```
private ApiInterface apiInterface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<JSONObject> call = apiInterface.getCheck();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONObject> call, Response<JSONObject> response) {
            try {
                JSONObject suggestion = response.body().getJSONObject("suggestion");
                Message message = new Message(suggestion.getJSONObject("message").getString("message_a"), 
                        suggestion.getJSONObject("message").getString("message_b"));
                Message message1 = new Message(suggestion.getJSONObject("message1").getString("message_a"), 
                        suggestion.getJSONObject("message1").getString("message_b"));
                Message message2 = new Message(suggestion.getJSONObject("message2").getString("message_a"), 
                        suggestion.getJSONObject("message2").getString("message_b"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONObject> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


}
```

Then set text tot hte TextView

```
textView.setText(message.getMessage_a());
textView.setText(message.getMessage_b());
```

Comment: Is it possible to do without changing Api response and do it in Object

Comment: So instead of creating ArrayList I have to create JSONObject Class?.

Comment: I wanted to set name of JSONObject in textview instead of values inside JSONObject, And Can I run it in for loop. @YuriPopiv

Comment: @AviSoni I updated the answer. But you cannot run response like this in the loop because `"suggestion"` is the `object` not `array`

Comment: Is there any other option to run in loop because response will always be different in suggestion and the size will also be different @YuriPopiv

Comment: @AviSoni the only way is to make proper json response like `"suggestion"["message":{},"message":{},"message":{}]`. Also accept answer if this info was helpful

Comment: Thanks a lot, But actually the Api response will not be able to change because it is coming from third party. @YuriPopiv

Comment: I Have Done, Thank You @YuriPopiv

Comment: @AviSoni you did not)